# triggering more commands rather Play 'run' only

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

When I try to run few commands with triggering in a Play project, say

```
~ ;run ;stage
```

, only `run` is triggering on source code changes. Is there a way to trigger both commands?

Play v.2.3.6 and sbt 0.13.7 are in use.

Comment: It isn't complete decision, but here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!folder/current/play-framework/potj_APa6mU Alex has suggested very acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Try `~run`.

I don't think you should use `stage` when doing development. `stage` is used to create folder (inside target/universal) that you can to package and run the app when you want to deploy it in test or production.

Comment: Test to make sure that `stage` is the problem by running some innocuous second command like `about` or `help` and see if it executes in the terminal

Comment: Soumya Simanta, yes, I need updated stage as far as developing distributed application I want to run plenty of simultaneous main()s.

Comment: Ben Reich, the Play's `run` is the problem.